# Weird product of casting

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

When I'm casting like below, I'm getting something weird. My intention was to get something like this:

```
Inside Base
Inside Derived1
```

but I get infinite number of "Inside Base"... Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void somefunc()
    {
        cout << "Inside Base\n";
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->somefunc();
    }
};

class Derived1: public Base<Derived1>
{
public:
    void somefunc()
    {
        cout << "Inside Derived1\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Base<Derived1> b1;
    b1.somefunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To get the desired output, you'd have to define `Derived1 b1;` in `main`. Currently, you have Undefined Behaviour, since you cast a pointer to an object of type `Base<Derived1>` to a `Derived1` pointer. The object is not of type `Derived1` though.

Comment: Casting to `Derived1*` is not going to change the pointers in the vtable. You have an object of type `Base<T>`, so calling `somefunc` on a pointer pointing to it will call the instance of `somefunc` corresponding to that class.

Comment: This is the weirdest code I've ever seen, can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Kam It looks like the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour. Here is a shorter snippet with the same principle:

```
struct Base { };
struct Derived: Base { int x; };

int main()
{
    Base b;
    static_cast<Derived &>(b).x = 5;
}
```

It's still undefined even if `x` is not present, but I added it to help illustrate the problem. You're working on the object `b` however whereabouts in memory is this `5` being written?

The rule is that if you are using `static_cast` to case from a base class to a derived class, you have to check that the thing you are casting actually points/refers to an instance of that derived class . If it is then it works; if not then it's silent undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Mohammad Ali Baydoun is correct in his statement about the vtable not being updated when you perform the cast.

When you call `b1.somefunc()` in `main`, since `b1` is a `Base<Derived1>`, `Base<Derived1>::somefunc()` will get called. When you perform the cast to `Derived1`, the vtable isn't updated and the object you're casting is still internally a `Base<Derived1>` and not a `Derived1`. The vtable lookup results in another call to `Base<Derived1>::somefunc()` instead of `Derived1::somefunc()` and the result is infinite recursion.

This is, however, undefined behavior because you are casting the base class object into something it's not. Putting Derived1 as a template parameter doesn't make it defined behavior.

Comment: You're right. I over looked that. I edited my answer to emphasise that.